# When date enter in cell A how to automatic define value enter in cell B

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have Google sheet, I want that when I enter a value(date) in Column A (Cell A) then predefined value (125) automatic insert in cell B. Is there any way? any formula?
I found this formula but unable to modify for my requirement:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A81=paid),"paid",(NOW()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be of some help:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(year(A2:A)=2019,125,"?"))
```

but it only works for this year (2019).